# List from datagridview gives System.InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, class, for-loop, datagridview

I have a class called GetKoord in which I want to read a datagridview from and put it into a list. I've made a class vertEl which I made because I got an error with recursive stackoverflowexception at first.

The problem with this code comes when I'm in my public partial class try to make a list from vertElementerDgv. The loop in my class to add list-items doesn't work properly and gives the exception.

I appreciate all the help I can get! If some info is missing tell me and I'll provide it as good as I can.

```
GetKoord getKoord = new GetKoord();


    //Opens the file dialog and assigns file path to Textbox
    OpenFileDialog browseButton = new OpenFileDialog();
    private void browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DGV = nylpDgv;
        browseButton.Filter = "Excel Files |*.xlsx;*.xls;*.xlsm;*.csv";
        if (browseButton.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ExcelPath.Text = browseButton.FileName;
            fileExcel = ExcelPath.Text;
            //SetAttributeValue(ExcelPath, fileExcel);
            //nylp();

            /*
            ////IMPORTERER 10TAB-DATA FRA EXCEL TIL DATAGRIDVIEW////
            tenTabLine.fileExcel = fileExcel;
            tenTabLine.tenTab(tenTabDgv);
            */            

            ////IMPORTERER NYLPDATA TIL DATAGRIDVIEW////
            nylpLine.fileExcel = fileExcel;
            nylpLine.nylpData(nylpDgv);

            ////TAR DATA I NYLPDGV DATAGRIDVIEW OG BEREGNER VERTIKALE ELEMENTER////
            vertElementer.vertBueDGV(nylpDgv, vertElementerDgv);

            ////HENTER KOORDINATER////
            var TEST = getKoord.vertList(vertElementerDgv); //THIS IS CAUSING ERROR
            MessageBox.Show(TEST[5].elNr.ToString());


        }
        else return;
    }
```

The GetKoord class and vertEl class are as followed:

```
class GetKoord
{

    List<vertEl> vertTEST = new List<vertEl>(); 

    public List<vertEl> vertList(DataGridView VertElementer)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<VertElementer.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            vertTEST.Add(new vertEl
            {
                elNr = (int)VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value,
                p1 = (double)VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value,
                p2 = (double)VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value,
                z1 = (double)VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value,
                z2 = (double)VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value,
                heln1 = (double)VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value,
                heln2 = (double)VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value
            });

        }

        return vertTEST;
    }



    /*
    public double zKoord(double pNr)
    {

       // zKoord() = 

        return zKoord(pNr);

    }
    */

}

class vertEl
{
    private int _elNr;
    private double _p1;
    private double _p2;
    private double _z1;
    private double _z2;
    private double _nylpRad;
    private double _heln1;
    private double _heln2;

    public int elNr
    {
        get { return _elNr; }
        set { _elNr = value; }
    }

    public double p1
    {
        get { return _p1; }
        set { _p1 = value; }
    }

    public double p2
    {
        get { return _p2; }
        set { _p2 = value; }
    }

    public double z1
    {
        get { return _z1; }
        set { _z1 = value; }
    }

    public double z2
    {
        get { return _z2; }
        set { _z2 = value; }
    }

    public double nylpRad
    {
        get { return _nylpRad; }
        set { _nylpRad = value; }
    }

    public double heln1
    {
        get { return _heln1; }
        set { _heln1 = value; }
    }

    public double heln2
    {
        get { return _heln2; }
        set { _heln2 = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you  getting?

Comment: [Screenshot](https://content.screencast.com/users/fjaosl/folders/Jing/media/62d7ba82-711a-46ea-b957-db99ddcc85a0/2017-02-02_1302.png)

See the screenshot. It says InvalidCastException.

EDIT: If I comment out heln1 and heln2 the code works:

//heln1 = (double)VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value,

//heln2 = (double)VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value

Answer (score 0):

The data types of Excel are not always the one you are expecting and you are casting into. You have to convert the values by your own:

```
vertTEST.Add(new vertEl
{
    elNr = Convert.ToInt32(VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value),
    p1 = Convert.ToDouble(VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value),
    p2 = Convert.ToDouble(VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value),
    z1 = Convert.ToDouble(VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value),
    z2 = Convert.ToDouble(VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value),
    heln1 = Convert.ToDouble(VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value),
    heln2 = Convert.ToDouble(VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value)
});
```

Comment: //heln1 = (double)VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value,
If I comment out heln1 it works. Actually I'm not getting the values from Excel. Initially I do, but I have a calculation from at datagridview (nylpDGV) to another datagriview (vertElementerDgv) which I hope stores the calculated values as the types I converted them to.

Answer (score 0):

From what your comments and code show, I am confident you are getting this error from one of the `Value` conversions. Example, if one of the cells in the `DataGridView` is empty and you try to cast this “Empty” value to a double you will get this error.

Checking for these null values and bad number formats should be done either way, but especially when trying to cast a string to a number. There is always the possibility that the string is not a number. Assuming the values are all correct the other possibility is the added row in a `DataGridView`. So just taking a guess here, I would suggest two ways to help find where this error is coming from. First, check for null values and use a `tryParse` to help weed out bad int/double values. Also use a `foreach` to loop through the rows.

First create a new List to hold the `vertEl` objects. The `tempInt` and `tempDouble` variables are used to hold each `tryParse` result. You may have seen the `tryParse` used in an `if` statement like below

```
Int result = 0;
If (int.tryParse(someString, out result) {
  // here the parse was successful – result is a valid number
}
else {
  //  either null or bad number format – result is still valid and is set to zero.
}
```

This is one way you could figure out where your error is coming from by adding a check for a null cell or the value in the cell is a bad number format. The code below simply ignores bad values and sets a default value of zero (0) for these bad values. The `tryParse` will return false if the string is null or is an invalid number format. In this case we really do not care which one; we will simply set this value to zero (0) which is what the `tryParse` returns in its out variable when the parse fails. So checking if it fails or succeeds is unnecessary. If it fails, the returned number will be zero. Hope this helps.

```
private List<vertEl> GetVertList() {
  List<vertEl> vertTEST = new List<vertEl>();
  int tempInt = 0;
  double tempDouble = 0.0;
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in VertElementer.Rows) {
    if (!row.IsNewRow) {
      vertEl vert1 = new vertEl();
      int.TryParse(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString(), out tempInt);
      vert1.elNr = tempInt;
      double.TryParse(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), out tempDouble);
      vert1.p1 = tempDouble;
      double.TryParse(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString(), out tempDouble);
      vert1.p2 = tempDouble;
      double.TryParse(row.Cells[3].Value.ToString(), out tempDouble);
      vert1.z1 = tempDouble;
      double.TryParse(row.Cells[4].Value.ToString(), out tempDouble);
      vert1.z2 = tempDouble;
      double.TryParse(row.Cells[5].Value.ToString(), out tempDouble);
      vert1.heln1 = tempDouble;
      double.TryParse(row.Cells[6].Value.ToString(), out tempDouble);
      vert1.heln2 = tempDouble;
      vertTEST.Add(vert1);
    }
  }
  return vertTEST;
}
```